# C# DateTime stack memory

Tags: c#, datetime, memory, stack

1) `DateTime.Now` returns a new `DateTime` instance.

2) `DateTime.Subtract` returns a new `TimeSpan` instance.

3) `DateTime` is a structure so occupies memory in the stack.

4) When a method exits (returns), its stack memory is reclaimed.

Therefore, does the following code save memory (assuming `StartTiming` method is in the same class containing Main)?

**Code 1:**

```
static Main(){

bool started = true;
static TimeSpan totalTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
static DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

while(started){
        // my assumption: every time the method is called, the same memory 
        // in the stack will be reused
        StartTiming();
    }
}

void StartTiming(){
     totalTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime);   
}
```

compared to the following code

**Code 2:**

```
static Main(){    

bool started = true;
TimeSpan totalTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

while(started){
     // my assumption: every time this stmt is executed  DateTime.Now 
     // creates a new DateTime instance and Subtract creates a timespan instance
     totalTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime);
    }
```

}

Comment: Same memory. And structs not always go to the stack. For the why (of the "Not always go to the stack" read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx

Comment: The code doesn't even compile...

Comment: A DateTime is just 8 bytes.  Don't worry about it.

Comment: My advise: Stop worrying about this (premature optimisation), and use the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class.

Comment: CodeInChaos: just extract the static variables to the class level, or use "CONST" keyword instead of static. Anyways, the main part of the code is "DateTime.Now.Subract()".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably find that the `StartTiming()` method in Code 1 has been inlined by the JIT compiler so both versions produce same machine code.

What is more, since the method doesn't take any parameters no stack is used.

And what you are probably doing is a premature optimisation... ;-)

Comment: Inlining is done by the JIT compiler. So IL will be different, but the resulting machine-code will be the same.

Comment: For clarification: Method parameters are not the only reason for a method to be assigned memory on stack. it still requires stack memory for local variables.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately I wouldn't have thought it would make any difference because the stack for the method is prepared according to the size of the local variables that are required for it in advance (the compiler figures this all out).

All that's changing between the two (slightly strange, it must be said) bits of code is that fewer bytes are being created and cleaned up on entry/exit - the ultimate overhead is the same.

Then there's the effects of compiler optimisations to consider - i.e. if a variable is only ever used in one way after being initialised, the compiler often will optimise the variable away in the IL.

Note only that but then there's JIT optimisations to consider - as another answerer has also pointed out - for example, the 8 bytes required for the DateTime might just as well be mapped to a CPU register; in which case there is no 'allocation' or 'cleaning up' in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You are fretting over saving 0.0015% of the memory used by the stack.  This is not even an absolute savings, the memory used by an activation frame is re-used when the method exits.  Replacing a local variable by a static one achieves the *exact* opposite, the memory for static variables is *not* re-used.  It will occupy memory for the life-time of the program.  Static variables are also a very fertile source of bugs, especially when you use threading.

Bad Idea, all around.